# Single page application with Polymer and node.js, Where to store user information to reduce API calls?

Tags: polymer, single-page-application, session-storage

We are creating single page application using loopback and polymer.
We are at the stage to decide where to store user related information which is being accessed in different components of polymer. As the user information is common and we do not want to make API call every time to have it.

Is it a good idea to store it on HTML5 session storage?

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can't use a javascript variable?

Comment: What if user refreshes?

Comment: Yes it's a good idea. Local Storage too in complement.